# How to make this type of shape in react

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I want to create this shape in react. I am able to code some of the parts but the border is creating issues.

[Image Link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1amR.png)

[What I am able to produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zae80.png)

Answer (score -1):

Yo can use z-index property to achieve it.Set the z-index of vertical line to higher number than horizontal line and make sure both overlap each other at there intersection point.